# Override select2 container z-index already declared is CSS

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

I am working on a website design, but this thing driving me crazy.

I have select2 dropdowns on some pages in the theme, which works fine. In the theme CSS file there is a line to set the z-index for the containers:

```
.select2-container {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Now on an other page this is not visible as the modal has a higher z-index number. I tried to override the z-index of the container by specifying its path:

```
div.test-body .select2-container {
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

It seems to be overriding the element on the console, but the dropdown is not appearing, until I manually untick the original declaration mentioned above. Div.test-body also has a position:fixed on it.

Is there a workaround which could work maybe? The first code loaded first in the theme structure, I do not know if it helps or not.

Comment: Since we can't see full code, try to put position: relative to div.test-body

Comment: Unfortunately it is already have a position:fixed on it.